# How exception which is raised in RestController gets transferred to End client who called RestEnd point?

Tags: spring, http, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I want to understand how the exception which is thrown in `RESTEnd point` is "transferred" to the client who invoked the REST end point.

```
@GetMapping"/v1/xyz/{param}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public ResponseEntity<String> doSomeWork() {

   if(normal) {
    // return value

  }
  else {

        throw new SomeException()
  }  
}
```

During normal flow, it returns the ResponseEntity.

My doubt is, when this rest controller throws an exception, how that goes cascaded to client who invoked the rest end point?

Answer (score 0):

The exception would be communicated to the client through the ResponseEntity like this:

```
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceLayer service;

    @GetMapping"/v1/xyz/{param}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> doSomeWork() {
        try {
            service.doSomeWork();
        } catch(SomeException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
            return new ResponseEntity<>("some string", OK);
    } 
}
```

I would use a service layer that throws some exception if it's operation fails. Then return a 500 response that tells the client about it!